# Understand commands of a class file

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing, renewcommand

I haven't much experience with TeX/LaTex and I am trying to write a CV based on [this](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex) repository.

Specifically, I am trying to understand how a LaTeX class file is written, and reproduce to a certain extend the class file of this repository, since it is quite similar with what I would like to do.

I cannot understand the code in [lines](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex/blob/f7815bd4d39e39ee58648666937810eb7b4f7836/twentysecondcv.cls#L96) 96 and 99. What is the purpose of defining a command and then redefining it? I also cannot understand what the command does, and it doesn't seem that the author uses it somewhere.

Can someone explain briefly?

Comment: there is no purpose at all to defining it then redefining it, you could delete line 96 and change \renewcommnd to \newcommand at line 99. Or as you say you could delete both lines as the command isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no purpose at all to defining it then redefining it, you could delete line 96 and change `\renewcommnd` to `\newcommand` at line 99. Or as you say you could delete both lines as the command isn't used.